# How to build the syntactic tree of this formula

Tags: predicate-logic

Consider the following formula:

∃x(Ux & ∀y((Ay & Ixy) ⊃ Fxy))

I would like to build the syntactic tree of this formula but I'm getting confused about how to do it. In particular, I don't know how to treat operators like ∃: do I have to treat them as connectives like & or not?

With the expression "syntactic tree" I mean a tree-like diagram that traces the "syntactic history" of a formula by showing how the formula is constructed from atomic formulas by means of applications of the definition of a well-formed formula (in this case a well-formed formula of a predicate language).

The complexity of a formula is given by the number of connectives it contains (e.g.: formula which contains 3 connectives is a formula of a complexity 3). Here is an example: consider the formula Px ⊃ Qab. The "root" of the tree is Px ⊃ Qab itself, which has complexity 1, and the "leaves" are Px and Qab, two formulas of complexity 0.

Comment: A quantifier has a *scope*, which is the subformula to which it applies.  When drawing the syntax tree, make the quantifier a node with one child, namely the subformula that is its scope.

Comment: I also thought you had to do what you suggest but then in the lecture notes I'm reading I found this exercise: How many leaves has the syntactic tree of  ∀x∀yAxy? Answer: 1.

Comment: Also what would be the complexity of the formula I proposed in my question?

Comment: It's possible that the lecture notes discuss rules to collapse certain subtrees.  For instance, nodes with one child can be merges with their only child.  The exercise may then refer to the size of the collapsed tree. I prefer, though, the syntax tree to reflect the definition of syntax and semantics of the language.  As for the fomula at the top of your post, I count 15 nodes for a syntax tree.

Comment: If you count connectives, there are three of them in the formula above.

Comment: So ∃ wouldn't count as a connective?

Comment: And ∀y neither.

Comment: In most definitions, $\exists$ and $\forall$ are not considered connectives.  They are simply called "quantifiers," and they form their own class of symbols.

Comment: So if I understand well what Fabio suggested in his first comment (so independently from what my lecture notes say) the "only child" of my formula would be Ux & ∀y((Ay & Ixy) ⊃ Fxy)

Comment: Yes, you got what I meant.

Comment: If this is the case that means you can have a child of a node which has the same complexity as his father (the same number of connectives, as you don't count ∃ as a connective).

Comment: According to that definition, yes.

Comment: As for me, I count 9 nodes for the formula I proposed! I think we adopted a different approach.

Comment: You probably count $Ux$ as a single node.

Comment: Yes! Can you count it as something else?

Answer (score 0):

"$\exists x$" is not an operator.

The operator is
"$\exists$"
and it has two nodes:
the first lists all the variables
(in this case, just "x")
and the second describes
what is true about the variables.

Comment: Could you develop a bit please?

Comment: I corrected the error about ∃

Answer (score 0):

The root must be $\exists x$ with only one child : $\land$ (conjunction).

The $\land$ node has to branches: the left one with $Ux$ and the right one with $\forall y$.

$\forall y$ has only the $\to$ child, which in turn has two branches : left one is $∧$ (conjunction) and right one is $Fxy$.

In turn, the $\land$ node has two children : left is $Ay$ and right is $Ixy$.

Now you can check it rebuilding the formula bottom-up...

You can see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=zAchdqsWkL0C&pg=PA105) for a similar example.

Comment: So do you count 9 nodes?

Comment: @Fishermansfriend - Yes.

Comment: Could you explain for me how do you get 15 nodes using Fabio Somenzi's alternative method?

Comment: @Fishermansfriend - I've counted 9 nodes and not 15...

Comment: So did I, but Fabio found 15 so I was was asking myself what kind of method he used.